# there is a way not override the get and set when i make extention

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a property inside protocol and I make an extension to my class it forces me to override the set and get I want to able set and get the default

I tried to make it like the below but I get a warning "Function call causes an infinite recursion"

```
  var didSelectSpecificCoinClousre: didSelectHandler? {
        get {
            return self.didSelectSpecificCoinClousre
        }
        set(value) {
            self.didSelectSpecificCoinClousre = value
        }
    }
```

my protocol :

```
protocol SelectedSpecificCoinProtocol {
    
    typealias didSelectHandler = () -> (Void)?
    var didSelectSpecificCoinClousre:didSelectHandler? { get set }
    
}
```

Comment: Don't put the implementation in an extension. Then you don't have to write the getters and setters, and can write a stored property instead.

Comment: thanks, It works. but I would appreciate an explanation why when I implement via extension I have to override get set